# Why is my program overwriting the previous added account during serialization?

Tags: java, serialization

// My program is meant for serializing and deserializing an object of a Current account. It is successfullly reading and writing the data, but when i re-run the program again. The last written object is the only thing that appears. Is there any way I can change this code so that it writes each object and reads each object back in again. Do i need to serialize the whole arrayList, and if so, how do i do that? Here is my code.

```
package ie.lyit.bank;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CurrentFileHandler implements Serializable
{
    // Set up ArrayList to store currentAccount Objects
        private ArrayList<Current> currentAcc;

        // Set up default constructor
        public CurrentFileHandler()
        {
            // Construct currentAcc ArrayList
            currentAcc = new ArrayList<Current>();
        }   

        /** An Add method that creates an account, reads details of an account
         * and adds the account object to the ArrayList 
        **/
        public void add()
        {   // Create a currentAcc Object
            Current current = new Current();

            // Read its details
            current.read();

            // Add account to the ArrayList
            currentAcc.add(current);
            WriteRecordsToFile(current);
        }

        // A view method to allow a user to view an account
        public Current view()
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the account number for the account you wish to view: ");
            Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Read the account number of the account to be viewed from the user
            int accToView = keyboardIn.nextInt();

            // for every account object in currentAcc
            for(Current tmpCurrent: currentAcc)
            {
                // if it's number equals the number of accToView
                if(tmpCurrent.getAccountNo() == accToView)
            {
                // Display it
                System.out.println(tmpCurrent);
                return tmpCurrent;
            }
        }

            //  Account not found, return null
            System.out.println("Account Not Found.");
                return null;
        }

        // A list method to allow a user to list the account(s) 
        public void list()
        {
            // Loop through the ArrayList 
            for(Current tmpCurrent: currentAcc)
            // Display each account object 
            System.out.println(tmpCurrent);
        }

        // An Edit method to allow the user to view an account that they want to edit
        public void edit()
        {
            // Call view() to find, display and return the account to be edited
            Current tmpCurrent = view();
            // if the account was !null, i.e. it was found
            if(tmpCurrent != null)
            {
                // get it's index
                int index = currentAcc.indexOf(tmpCurrent);
                // Read in a new account and...
                tmpCurrent.read();
                // Reset it in the ArrayList
                currentAcc.set(index, tmpCurrent);
            }
        }
                // Delete method to allow the user to delete an account from the ArrayList
                public void delete()
                {
                    // Call view() to find, display and return the account to be deleted 
                    Current tmpCurrent = view();
                    // if the account was !null, i.e. it was not found
                    if(tmpCurrent != null)
                    // Remove it from currentAcc ArrayList
                        currentAcc.remove(tmpCurrent);
                }


        // Serialization and Deserialization Section...

        // A write record to file method
        // Serializes the ArrayList and reads it out into the file 

        public void WriteRecordsToFile(Current c)
        {
            final String FILENAME = "current.bin";
            try
            {
                // Serializes the ArrayList
                FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(FILENAME);

                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);

                System.out.println("Writing to file.... " + c);
                os.writeObject(c);
                os.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fNFE)
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot create file to store currentAcc.");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        // A read record from file method
        // Deserializes the ArrayList and reads it back into program
        public void ReadRecordsFromFile()
        {
            final String FILENAME = "current.bin";

            try
            {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FILENAME);

                ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

                System.out.println("Reading from file...");
                Current c;
                c = (Current)is.readObject();
                System.out.println(c);
                is.close();     
            }catch(FileNotFoundException fNFE)
            {
                System.out.println("Cannot find current file.");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }   

}// end class
```

Comment: Your comments say you're writing a list, but you only write one instance of Current. If you want to save a whole list, than do so, the exact same way you save a single Current now: `os.writeObject(list)`

Comment: ok, i changed it as you have advised. But i get this error now whilst reading it in. Is there as issue with the read records from file method: Reading from file...
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to ie.lyit.bank.Current

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to change the reading part accordingly. If you serialize a list, you must also expect a list when deserializing: `List<Current> list = (List<Current>) is.readObject()`

Comment: Its working perfectly now thank you. Is there anyway that i can get it to print a space between each account on printout as it looks quite cluttered. Here is my output: Reading from file...
[Account Number: 1
Name:Mr Joe Bloggs
Address:1 main street
Date opened:11/11/2016
Balance:€100.0 
Overdraft Available:€200.0// this is where i want the gap
, Account Number: 2
Name:Mr John Bloggs
Address:2 Main Stret
Date opened:12/11/2016
Balance:€200.0 
Overdraft Available:€400.0
]

Comment: so i basically need a gap printed between each account